# change color based on location

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to draw a simple square and change the color dynamically so that it is the brightest in the center and darkest in the borders.

however when I am rendering I can't see anything .

here is my vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;  
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;
varying vec4 pos;
void main()                    
{                            
    v_Color = a_Color;
    pos = u_Matrix * a_Position;
    gl_Position = pos;

}
```

and here is my fragment shader :

```
precision mediump float; 

varying vec4 v_Color;                                       
varying vec4 pos;
void main()                         
{                             
    float len = length(normalize(pos));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(1-len , 1-len , 1-len , 1);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the shader compilation & link success flags & logs?  The mixture of `int`s (`1`) and `float`s (`dist`) in that `vec4` constructor is suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference `gl_Position` in the fragment shader.

Either hand `gl_Position` over to the fragment shader

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
varying vec4 pos;

void main() 
{
    pos = a_Position;
    gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

or use `gl_FragCoord` in the fragment shader `float dist = length( gl_FragCoord - viewPortCenter );` if you want to work in window coordinates.

Also rather use `length`, which is faster, instead of doing your own distance calculation.

Comment: thank you for the answer . please take a look at my edited code as I have changed it but still I get the same result  - a blank black screen.

Comment: Are the fragments even landing on the screen? I mean if you just output a constant color do you see it?